# Unable to set SELINUX to permissive

Tags: centos7, selinux

Trying to set **SELINUX=permissive**

```
$getenforce

Disabled
```

This is the file content of  **/etc/selinux/config**

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
#SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

I reboot the server

```
shutdown -r now
```

but I get always **SELINUX=Disabled**

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Is there an administrative script running in the background that is modifying `selinux` at startup?

Comment: No. It's an scratch image of the server centos 7.4 to start to work